# Javascript executing when jQuery not ready

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following scenario is a problem I am having. I came to the conclusion that jQuery must not be ready when Javascript is executing by observing this scenario.

**Scenario:**

I have a Java application which injects Javascript script tags into the currently loaded DOM page. The following Java code runs inline Javascript which inserts **jquery.js** and **myCode.js**. **myCode.js** holds my Javascript codes.

```
 browser.executeJavaScript("var head= document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];" +
                                "var script= document.createElement('script');script.type= 'text/javascript';script.src= 'jquery.js';head.appendChild(script);" +
                                "var script4= document.createElement('script');script4.type= 'text/javascript';script4.src= 'http://myCode.js';head.appendChild(script4);");
```

In this Java application, I also have a *buttonListener* that fires a function in myCode.js in *ActionPerformed()*;

```
executedJS = browser.executeJavaScript("replaceAllLinks()");
```

The problem that is encountered is nullPointerException at the above line when button is clicked. Accomodating for null case results in endless loop without any changes.

```
while(executedJS == null) browser.executeJavaScript("replaceAllLinks()");
```

The cause of the problem was pinpointed down to when jQuery functions, methods are present inside *replaceAllLinks();* javascript function. when jQuery, methods were absent, no problems could be observed. There was not one instance of **nullPointerException** raised.

The only possible underlying issue would be that somehow jQuery library is not fully loaded while *replaceAllLinks();* is being executed. If jQuery methods and functions were not in use, it doesn't matter and everything runs okay.

My question is then, how can I make sure that jQuery is fully loaded and available for use?

Comment: Where is your $(document).ready ?

Answer (score 1):

Every script relying on jQuery should be contained inside a DOM ready function. Such a function normally takes this form:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    /* code here */
});
```

and a shortcut to achieve the same thing would be:

```
$(function() {
    /* code here */
});
```

Here's the documentation for further information on the ready method:
http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 0):

Declare some global variable `at the end` jquery.js, e.g.

```
window.jQueryIsLoaded=true;
```

and check this variable before using jQuery.

`<edit>`**Forget this, see  Salman A's comment below, should be the right answer.**`</edit>`

Comment: Infact, you can just check for `typeof jQuery !== 'undefined'`.

Comment: But how sure are you that jQuery is completely downloaded in this case?

Comment: OK, I took a look at jquery.js, has to be complete if jQuery is known.

Comment: what's weird is that jQuery is fully loaded....but the problem still occurs....so I was wrong ?